# Regex for LAS entries

Tags: c#, regex, log-ascii-standard

I am very bad with RegEx. Can anyone help me getting RegEx for this pattern.

Here is the pattern

(Words).(Single Character, can be empty)(white spaces)(words, can be empty):(Words, can be empty)

Here are the examples

```
VERS. 2.00: Ver 2.00
WRAP. NO:
STRT.F                  4501.0000:START DEPTH
WELL. C5 1H:WELL
FTG GTG. :LOCATION FOOTAGE DESCRIPTION
```

**Update 1:**

Here is what I have done.

```
string re1 = "((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 1
string re2 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re3 = "(\\.)";   // Any Single Character 1
string re4 = "(.)"; // Any Single Character 2
string re5 = "(\\s+)";  // White Space 1
string re6 = "((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 2
string re7 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re8 = "(:)"; // Any Single Character 3
string re9 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re10 = "(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";    // Uninteresting: word
string re11 = ".*?";    // Non-greedy match on filler
string re12 = "((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";  // Word 3

Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6 + re7 + re8 + re9 + re10 + re11 + re12, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**Update 2:**

Okay. I have tried something new. Here is my regex.

```
(\.)(.)(\s+)(4501.0000)(:)
```

Here is the input.

```
STRT DTG.F                  4501.0000:START DEPTH
```

And here is output.

```
STRT DTG
.
F

4501.0000
:
START DEPTH
```

Now I need to only replace 4501.0000 with regex for sentence (e.g. "some text" or "some more text"),

Comment: probably you need to recheck the LAS specification first, `(WORDS).` not necessarily true, it could be a space after `(WORDS)spacespacespace.`

Comment: We did some modifications to LAS. So it is not LAS format (you can say inspired),

Comment: @YuliamChandra Is it possible that there are two colon ":" in LAS line?,

Comment: based on my understanding, not possible, I wrote the converter couple years ago, your regex could be something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/yS7oC5/1), first mnem, 2nd unit, 3rd data, 4th desc

Comment: @YuliamChandra my understanding was same, but what if we are storing date/time value. It could be of form 11:12:35.

Comment: @YuliamChandra that regex is perfect. It doesn't cover the time issue which I wrote in pervious comment. I will do some research that this is possible or not. Thanks,

Comment: the time format should part of the data section and you can use different regex for data section, in your case it is only the header section I think, and data format is delimited by comma, that would be a lot of easier without regex, you need to read the full spec I could be mistaken remembering those spec

Comment: @YuliamChandra I found a case in which regex fails. For this input "VCLAY.V/V 123:clay volume" Note that V/V is the unit, but expression returns V as unit and "V 123" in value, can you help me in fixing the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header section of the LAS file (generally) has this kind of format.

```
<MNEM> .<UNIT> <DATA> : <DESCRIPTION>
```

The regex can be like this.

```
^([\w\s]*)\s*\.([^ ]*)\s*([^:]*)\s*:(.*)$
```

Explanation

```
^         -> beginning of line
([\w\s]*) ->   1st group, MNEM (take words and/or space)
\s*       -> space
\.        -> period delimiter
([^ ]*)     ->   2nd group, UNIT (take everything until it sees space)
\s*       -> space
([^:]*)   ->   3rd group, DATA (take everything until it sees colon)
\s*       -> space
:         -> colon delimiter
(.*)      ->   4th group, DESCRIPTION (take everything)
$         -> end of line
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nK5qM4/1)

Comment: Thanks, regex site is suburb,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez, I edit the pattern, change `\w` into `[^ ]` based on assumption that `UNIT` and `DATA` is separated by space

Comment: thanks, I also modified the expression, but that was returning 5 tokens, your new change handles the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

use 
     \s or " "
to include whitespace as well.
Something like

```
     ((?:[a-z][a-z\s]+))
```

or

```
      ((?:[a-z][a-z ]+))
```